# Based on the attached error output, why is my Unity3D build failing?

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I've got a unity game which I have built several times before. Today, build mysteriously failed with a large error message, the meaning of which is a mystery to me. Any help would be appreciated. I've tried reverting to a former working copy of my code and shutting down and restarting, to no avail. The error is as follows:

```
Failed running "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_Win\python\2.7.5.3_64bit\python.exe" "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc" @"C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Destructo\Assets\..\Temp\emcc_arguments.resp"

stdout:WARNING: sanity check failed to run [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\emscripten.config_sanity'
stderr:WARNING:root:did not see a source tree above or next to the LLVM root directory (guessing based on directory of C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten_FastComp_Win\llc), could not verify version numbers match
INFO:root:(Emscripten: Running sanity checks)
WARNING:root:java does not seem to exist, required for closure compiler, which is optional (define JAVA in C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\emscripten.config if you want it)
WARNING:root:closure compiler will not be available
WARNING:root:--separate-asm works best when compiling to HTML. otherwise, you must yourself load the '.asm.js' file that is emitted separately, and must do so before loading the main '.js` file
error: failure to execute js library "C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Destructo\Assets\Plugins\plugin.jslib": SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier,,SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier    at Object.load (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:173:14)    at JSify (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:59:20)    at C:\Users\Owner\Documents\Destructo\Assets\Plugins\plugin.jslib (C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:208:3)    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)preprocessed source (you can run a js engine on this to get a clearer error message sometimes):=============ï»¿mergeInto(LibraryManager.library, { SaveString: function(s){        fix = InterfaceOut;     url = "../interface/kabooka.php";       string = "save="+Pointer_stringify(s);      request(fix, url, string);  }   ReadString: function(){     string = "";        if(interfaceInput != null){         return string+interfaceInput;       }       return string;  }});=============Internal compiler error in src/compiler.js! Please raise a bug report at https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/issues/ with a log of the build and the input files used to run. Exception message: "SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" | SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier    at Object.load (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:173:14)    at JSify (eval at globalEval (C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:105:8), <anonymous>:59:20)    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\src\compiler.js:208:3)    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc", line 13, in <module>
  emcc.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emcc.py", line 1670, in run
final = shared.Building.emscripten(final, append_ext=False, extra_args=extra_args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\shared.py", line 1745, in emscripten
  call_emscripten(cmdline)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 1842, in _main
  temp_files.run_and_clean(lambda: main(
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\tempfiles.py", line 78, in run_and_clean
  return func()
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 1847, in <lambda>
  DEBUG=DEBUG,
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 1748, in main
  temp_files=temp_files, DEBUG=DEBUG)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 93, in emscript
  glue, forwarded_data = compiler_glue(metadata, settings, libraries, compiler_engine, temp_files, DEBUG)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\emscripten.py", line 296, in compiler_glue
  cwd=path_from_root('src'), error_limit=300)
  File "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\WebGLSupport\BuildTools\Emscripten\tools\jsrun.py", line 122, in run_js
  raise Exception('Expected the command ' + str(command) + ' to finish with return code ' + str(assert_returncode) + ', but it returned with code ' + str(proc.returncode) + ' instead! Output: ' + str(ret)[:error_limit])
Exception: Expected the command ['C:/Program Files/Unity/Editor/Data\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe', '--stack_size=8192', '--max-old-space-size=2048', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\Emscripten\\src\\compiler.js', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Destructo\\Temp\\EmscriptenTemp\\tmpm5ff0e.txt', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Audio.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Cursor.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Eval.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\FileSystem.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Logging.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Profiler.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\SystemInfo.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\UnetWebSocket.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\Video.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebCam.js', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\lib\\WebRequest.js', 'C:\\Users\\Owner\\Documents\\Destructo\\Assets\\Plugins\\plugin.jslib', 'C:\\Program Files\\Unity\\Editor\\Data\\PlaybackEngines\\WebGLSupport\\BuildTools\\Emscripten\\src\\library_pthread_stub.js'] to finish with return code 0, but it returned with code 1 instead! Output: // The Module object: Our interface to the outside world. We import
// and export values on it, and do the work to get that through
// closure compiler if necessary. There are various ways Module can be used:
// 1. Not defined. We create it here
// 2. A function parameter, function(Module) { ..gener
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

Comment: I really don't appreciate the downvote. This a pretty arcane error message, and the presumption that I've done no research is not at all helpful. It's not like it's easy to find solutions to such an obscure problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone else who might run into the same problem, I have found a solution.

I have been attempted to employ an interface between scripts in my game and scripts in the browser using a javascript plug-in. You can find unity's documentation on this here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-interactingwithbrowserscripting.html

Turns out that I foolishly failed to put a comma between method declarations in my javascript object. Monodevelop doesn't flag this error, and evidently it is possible to run the game in the Unity Editor without the commas, but not possible to build it (leading to my incorrect belief that I had reverted to code which was previously working).

It's a pretty big error message for a pretty small problem. So, make sure you put a comma between your method declarations.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and fixed it.

I deleted everything but the Assets folder in my Unity project, then reopened it, set all the necessary settings again and built it successfully.

It probably wasn't necessary to delete all of those folders, you can try deleting them one by one and see if it works after each one.

I don't know why I got the error in the first place, but never forget to just try deleting those pesky folders before going on a debugging campaign :D

[image: What to delete]